An issue with Git repo in Visual Studio results in failure to load .csproj file (not found/deleted)
So on a Windows 11 local repo, if I switch from Master to certain other branches using checkout, and then return to checkout Master, theProject.csproj file is not reloaded and checking in FileExplorer indeed confirms it cant be found. It marks a Delete change. Undo Changes brings it back.
But this is happening every time I checkout particular branches and then subsequently checkout the Master again.
If I checkout an innocent branch in between the problem is not evident, so it appears that the characteristics of a particular branch are influencing another.
There is no merge, push or pull, or any other kind of operation going on, just the changing of active branches. What is going on and how can I stop this behavior?

Can you provide the commands you run and screenshots of the terminal output if possible?
> git checkout misbehaving-branch

> git checkout master

Is it just those two commands that cause the issue? Do you run the commands any differently? What are the exact git commands?
Also, out of curiosity could you show us the terminal output of
> git status

a) when on the master branch before checkout to misbehaving-branch
b) when on the misbehaving-branch, after checking out to misbehaving-branch
c) when on the master branch, after checking out back to master branch
Also - does
> git switch

cause the same issue?
Weird issue - but this info would help.
